# Next.js NextUI Components Expanding on Page Load/Refresh

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextui

I'm new to using Next.js, and I'm experimenting with their updated "app directory". I'm not too familiar with the rendering and client/server components yet, but I understand when and where to declare components as client components. In NextUI, there's a collapse component which expands on click to show more information (sort of like a toggle if you've ever used Notion). My issue is when I load or reload the page, for the first second the component is expanded and all the contents of the collapse component are displayed and then it returns to the normal state. Anyone know if this is expected behavior for this component?

```
<Collapse.Group accordion={false}>
<Collapse title="Realms">
hi
this
is
content
</Collapse>
</Collapse.Group>
```

When rendered, the viewer sees "hi this is content" for a split second when the component expands itself.